# OSGi slf4j logging in Apache Sling/felix

Tags: java, maven, osgi, slf4j, sling

I am trying to use **slf4j logger** in my **OSGi bundle** for **Apache Sling.**

When adding the dependency and import tag to the POM.xml, the bundle remains in *resolved* state.

Am I something missing?

**Activator.class**

```
    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

    public class Activator implements BundleActivator {
    ...
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SampleServiceImpl.class);
    ...
```

**POM.xml**

```
<Import-Package>org.slf4j</Import-Package>
...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

[image: Apache Sling Web Console / Bundle View]

**EDIT**
*If I comment out the Logger instantiation and remove the imports from the Activator.class the service stays in resolved state. 
Once I remove the lines regarding slf4 in the POM, everything works.*

Comment: It would be useful to get a sample project somewhere, maybe on Github. Also, where are you deploying this - Sling Launchpad, custom launchpad, or something else?

Comment: I guess there was a misunderstanding from my side. 
There was a problem with the import package statement. The problem was not caused by slf4j .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your `<Import-Package>org.slf4j</Import-Package>` statement prevents other required packages from being imported. The value of that element should rather be `org.slfj4.*,*` so that all "automatic" imports are generated. See the [maven-bundle-plugin docs](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html) for more info.

But if your pom is similar to that of a Sling bundle like the [slingbucks sample](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/trunk/samples/slingbucks) you shouldn't need such explicit import statements anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have an exception in the start method of your Activator. Add a try catch and simply dump the exception on System.out to see what is going on. Did you also install some bundle that processes the slf4j logging like pax-logging?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! It's very hard to get answers once the question is tagged "apache sling".. 

I've tried this as well without success. If I comment out the Logger instantiation and remove the imports from the Activator.class the service stays in resolved state. 

Once I remove the lines regarding slf4 in the POM, everything works.
//Added this to my question as well.

**edit**
I have  sling.commons.logservice + sling.commons.log installed.